# Error: { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }

Tags: node.js

Fotolog is closing recently and I wanted to backup all of mine photos on there. Looking for something useful, I found this project: https://github.com/firstdoit/fotolog-backup

I installed npm and coffee with the instructions on the readme

but when I try to run:

```
 coffee fotolog-build-index.coffee ticinowriting2
```

I receive this error:

```
doc@doc-mtn:~/fotolog-backup$ coffee fotolog-build-index.coffee ticinowriting2
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
```

The code in "fotolog-build-index" is:

```
 request = require 'request'
$ = require 'cheerio'
fs = require 'fs'

imageURLs = []
user = process.argv[2]
throw new Error("Usage: coffee fotolog-build-index.coffee <username>") unless user

buildIndexFromPage = (page) ->
request "http://www.fotolog.com.br/#{user}/mosaic/#{page}", (err, resp, html) ->
    return console.error(err)  if err
    console.log "finished page #{page}... adding images"

    images = $.load(html)("a.wall_img_container img")
    images.map (i,img) ->
        imageURLs.push $(img).attr("src").replace('_t','_f')

    if images.length < 30
        console.log imageURLs
        console.log "got #{imageURLs.length} images"
        fs.writeFileSync('index.json', JSON.stringify(imageURLs))
    else
        buildIndexFromPage(page + 30)

buildIndexFromPage(0)
```

Sorry for my bad english, im from switzerland and i know quite nothing about this kind of code

Answer (score 0):

That error means the DNS resolver could not resolve the hostname (`www.fotolog.com.br`) to an IP address. I can verify this is indeed the case (`dig` gets `NXDOMAIN`). So unless you have the IP address there's not much you can do.

You could try just `www.fotolog.com` since that does seem to resolve yet, however the message on that site indicates data should have been downloaded before February 20, 2016.

Comment: Thank you, I tried with info.fotolog.com and it worked! Thanks a lot